# Why OWASP ZAP detect SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection, slim, zap

I'd like to know why OWASP ZAP detect potential SQL injection on my login page. I call an API to connect my users.

**PHP slim API code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, idGroup, idTeam,lastName, firstName, isLogged, login, phoneNumber, webrtc FROM users WHERE enable = 1 AND login = :login AND password = :password";
       
$db = new db();
$db = $db->connect();

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$userPass = md5($password);
$stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $userPass);

$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

**Login page:**

```
$login = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $apiUrl . 'agent/login', [
   'form_params' => [
       'login' => $login,
       'password' => $password,
       'ipAddress' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
   ]
]);

$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

if (isset($data[0]['id']) && $data[0]['id'] > 0) {
   $_SESSION['fullName'] = $data[0]['firstName'] . ' ' . $data[0]['lastName'];
   $_SESSION['idGroup'] = $data[0]['idGroup'];
   $_SESSION['idTeam'] = $data[0]['idTeam'];
   $_SESSION['idUser'] = $data[0]['id'];
   $_SESSION['login'] = $data[0]['login'];
   $_SESSION['phoneNumber'] = $data[0]['phoneNumber'];
   $_SESSION['webrtc'] = $data[0]['webrtc'];

   //Get roles for user
   $response = $client->request('GET', $apiUrl . 'web/permissions/' . $login);
   $data = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);

   foreach ($data as $roles) {
       $_SESSION['roles'][$roles['bit']] = $roles['name'];
   }

   echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

}
```

All my APIs use prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Here's the OWASP ZAP alert:

> The page results were successfully manipulated using the boolean
> conditions [ZAP" AND "1"="1" -- ] and [ZAP" AND "1"="2" -- ] The
> parameter value being modified was NOT stripped from the HTML output
> for the purposes of the comparison Data was returned for the original
> parameter.

Comment: I think it's because of this `md5($password)`. MD5 does not prevent SQL injection and is also bad practice today.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if the response page for the form submission contains the value of a form field as it was specified by a user. For instance if you are logging in your user and use the value of 'username' field to greet the user but pull it not from the DB but from the request variables. SQL injection does not take place but the scanning script assumes that you stored the value unsanitized in the DB while you just using the value provided by a user and not the value that you have stored in the DB. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for response.
There is no solution on client or application side to disable alert?

Comment: I'm not sure what OWASP ZAP does and how it works so I don't know if it is possible to turn certain alerts on or off. Based on the error/alert you getting you should be able to resolve the issue with some code/logic changes. I don't see all the code involved so it is hard to tell what to change. It might be something as simple as when you submit wrong username/password, the backend in some cases just returns the values that you put in and pre-fills the login form for you.

Comment: We have a FAQ for how to deal with false positives in ZAP: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-i-handle-a-false-positive/

Comment: I'll secure my code and report false positive if necessary.